# sed substitution (s) grouping is not working

Tags: regex, bash, sed

i have a problem with my regex for sed. It seems that grouping does not work properly and i can not find out why.

I tried this and many derivates of this command:

```
sed -er "/s/^(\>[\w\d]+\=[\d]+)_.+\]_([\d])$/\1\2/" test.fa
```

on this string (file) [ATTENTION: the '>' were removed by this form and is in front of every `TRINITY`, lines are alternating ID (`>TRINITY` and so on) and sequences (uppercase letters, with asterisks) linebreak (-> here space) is missing]:

```
>TRINITY_DN41792_c0_g3_i1_len=553_path=[700:0-121_707:122-163_706:164-240_694:241-552]_[-1,_700,_707,_706,_694,_-2]_3 KMA
>TRINITY_DN41806_c0_g1_i1_len=213_path=[245:0-129_246:130-147_247:148-212]_[-1,_245,_246,_247,_-2]_1 NSIAP
>TRINITY_DN41806_c0_g1_i1_len=213_path=[245:0-129_246:130-147_247:148-212]_[-1,_245,_246,_247,_-2]_2 TQ*LHIL
>TRINITY_DN41806_c0_g1_i1_len=213_path=[245:0-129_246:130-147_247:148-212]_[-1,_245,_246,_247,_-2]_3 LNS
>TRINITY_DN41788_c0_g1_i1_len=188_path=[208:0-97_209:98-128_210:129-152_211:153-187]_[-1,_208,_209,_210,_211,_-2]_1
*KLCT
>TRINITY_DN41788_c0_g1_i1_len=188_path=[208:0-97_209:98-128_210:129-152_211:153-187]_[-1,_208,_209,_210,_211,_-2]_2 ENCA
>TRINITY_DN41788_c0_g1_i1_len=188_path=[208:0-97_209:98-128_210:129-152_211:153-187]_[-1,_208,_209,_210,_211,_-2]_3 KI
>TRINITY_DN41788_c0_g2_i1_len=167_path=[212:0-97_213:98-128_214:129-152_215:153-166]_[-1,_212,_213,_214,_215,_-2]_1
*KLCT
>TRINITY_DN41788_c0_g2_i1_len=167_path=[212:0-97_213:98-128_214:129-152_215:153-166]_[-1,_212,_213,_214,_215,_-2]_2 ENC
>TRINITY_DN41788_c0_g2_i1_len=167_path=[212:0-97_213:98-128_214:129-152_215:153-166]_[-1,_212,_213,_214,_215,_-2]_3 KIVH
>TRINITY_DN41788_c1_g1_i1_len=183_path=[154:0-182]_[-1,_154,_-2]_1 YGS
>TRINITY_DN41788_c1_g1_i1_len=183_path=[154:0-182]_[-1,_154,_-2]_2 TDPRTVP
>TRINITY_DN41788_c1_g1_i1_len=183_path=[154:0-182]_[-1,_154,_-2]_3 RIPGQF
```

I want to get rid of the middle: '_path=' to the last '_'

What am i missing?

Comment: It looks like you didn't mark you question answered, but have abandoned this question-- from what I read in a comment.  I'm hoping my solution is actually helpful, I seem to waste time on SO here lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's too many regex sets :(  Try this, I removed the second grouping, b/c if you only want to remove the middle part, you don't need it.  The switch will only effect what's matched.  I try to use strong quotes, over double-quotes unless there is a reason not to.

`sed -r 's/(^>.*=[0-9]+)_.+\]_/\1/' test.fa`

From a line like this:
`>TRINITY_DN41806_c0_g1_i1_len=213_path=[245:0-129_246:130-147_247:148-212]_[-1,_245,_246,_247,_-2]_1 NSIAP`

I get this:
`>TRINITY_DN41806_c0_g1_i1_len=2131 NSIAP`

With out an example of your expected output, I have to trust I read your explanation correctly.

edit: I had no luck using \w and \d with sed's extended regex

Comment: Great job, but sed seems a bit strange. I will probably not use it again.

Comment: You'll notice that there's several versions of regex.  It's regex that's strange-- when you switch between applications using different ones :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried it in Python, and it seems your regexp is Ok except for the last `$`.
Here is my try:

```
"^(\>\w+\=\d+)_.+\]_(\d)"
```

I Removed the unnecessary character sets. 
The problem was that the `$` designates the end of the string, which is not true, since the pattern captures the digit after the last underscode, which is not the end of the string.

The regexp can even be shorter:

```
"([^=]+=\d+).*_(\d)"
```

`[^=]+` take all symbols that are not `=`

`=` then take the `=` sign

`.*_` then everything until the last underscore

`(\d)` then a digit

Comment: Thanks, that's a better solution. I validated my regex with the help of Pythex and there was no problem with the EOL - nevertheless i already tried it without '$'. Unfortunately this does not work either. I found a solution with awk now.